# Debugging a project that uses C++ and C# projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, extern

I'm currently using a project that uses several C# and C++ projects. I have a test project (in C#) I'm using to test some functionality - I have several print statements to help me debug issues. All of the print statements in my C# files appear in the console window, but all printf lines in my C++ projects do now show up. I'm unsure if this is even possible. If not, how do you go about viewing any print statements you place inside C++ files?

Here's a watered down version of my test project function flow:

```
static void hyperSlabTest()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hyperslab test.");
    double[,,] hyperslab = sourceFile.GetHyperslab(rowStart, columnStart, x, y);
}
```

This connects to this:

```
public double[,,] GetHyperslab(int rowStart, int columnStart, xWidth, yHeight)
{
     Console.WriteLine("GetHyperslab entered.");

     try{
          IntPtr ptr = FileAccess.getPingDataHyperslab(rowStart, columnStart, xWidth, yWidth);
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Error getting hyperslab.", ex);
     }
}
```

which connects to this:

```
[DllImport("HDF.Test.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr getDataHyperslab(
     [In] int rowStart,
     [In] int columnStart,
     [In] int xWidth;
     [In] int yWidth;
);
```

which finally calls this function in my C++ code (this function is also defined in my header file):

```
TEST_DLL void* getDataHyperslab(int& rowStart, int& columnStart, int& xWidth, int& yWidth)
{
     printf("Getting hyperslab...");

     // stuff....
}
```

When I run the test project, everything in the C# files runs fine and their print statements show up in the console window that appears, however, the `printf` line in my C++ file never shows. I've tried adding a breakpoint on that line in Visual Studio but that didn't help either. Any ideas?

Comment: Am I reading this correctly you have IntPtr on the prototype but void* on declaration of the body. Is that how it is supposed to be

Comment: @glant Yes. I am going off of existing methods that work fine i.e. the function above is extremely similar to an existing function in my source code (which I didn't right - I'm adding new functionality to this project).

Comment: @Roka545 Are reference parameters to DLL's safe if you're interfacing to a non C++ caller?  All of the DLL's I've created that export functions do not use reference parameters, as a reference is a C++ idiom, and not something you can definitely translate to another language.  What I would have expected are pointers to `int`, not referece to int.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug tab > tick the "Enable native code debugging" checkbox so you can set a breakpoint in the C++ code.  The only good reason to not see printf() output is the one you describe, not getting a break means it doesn't execute.